# Swift type does not conform to protocol NilLiteralConvertible

Tags: swift

I have method:

```
func  getByEmail(email:String) -> MeeterAccount{
   for  acct in accountsList  {
     if  acct.getEmail().equalsIgnoreCase(email)  {
    return acct;
    }
}
  return nil; // here I get an error: type 'MeeterAccount' does not conform to protocol NilliteralConvertible
}
```

How to get rid of this error?

I thought to write something like that:

```
func  getByEmail(email:String) -> MeeterAccount{

    var out:MeeterAccount!

    for  acct in accountsList  {
        if  acct.getEmail().equalsIgnoreCase(email)  {
            out = acct
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

That doesn't throw this error. Sounds like Swift makes me write only 2nd way.

Why I can't return `nil`?

Comment: The second version compiles, but likely leads to crashes, if you try to return nil.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If your function can return `nil`, then it should be declared as `... -> MeeterAccount?` (an optional type). Then the caller knows that it can be nil. (Your second example works but would crash because `return out` will implicitly try to unwrap nil.)

Answer (score 10):

## Explanation

> literal convertible protocols

When you assign a variable, for example

```
var a = 9.0
```

9.0 is the literal for the value assigned in variable a. By definition literal is a ***notation representing a fixed value***

What my eye sees there is **(nine dot zero)** And my mind interpret it as the float value 9.0. So do the compiler. Compiler sees (nine dot zero) literal and then it knows how to assign correct value from that literal.

Swift provided a way to hook into how values are constructed from the literals by compiler. They are the literal convertible protocols.

say I have a function

```
func returnString() -> String{
   return nil
}
```

> Error :  Type 'String' does not conform to protocol
>   'NilLiteralConvertible'

if I try to return 3

> Error :  Type 'String' does not conform to protocol
>   'IntegerLiteralConvertible'

The type `String` conforms to protocol `StringLiteralConvertible` which makes a match only when you return string literal (e.g `""`)

### But

```
func returnString() -> String?{
   return nil
}
```

This should work.

### Why?

Because here the return type is not `String` but `Optional` which is introduced by Swift. `Optional` implements the protocol `NilLiteralConvertible`. There you are allowed to return `nil`.

Hope I managed to explain behind the seen in a simple way.

Answer (score 6):

You can mark the return type as optional in the function signature (note the '?' at the end of `MeeterAccount`)

```
func  getByEmail(email:String) -> MeeterAccount? {
```